# Access @ViewScoped bean from custom component

Tags: jsf, components, cdi, view-scope, backing-beans

I have a custom JSF component that has an attribute that references a method within a backing bean by EL expression. The referenced method should be called as part of the component's decode process.

This works quite well for a @SessionScoped bean, but when I switch to a @ViewAccessScoped bean the reference to the backing bean's method obtained by

```
ValueExpression ve = getValueExpression("callbackToMethod");
String expression = ve.getExpressionString();

Application application = context.getApplication();
ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();

MethodExpression methodExpression = expressionFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, expression, String.class, new Class[0]);
methodExpression.invoke(elContext, new Object[0]);
```

is not the one in the bean backing the XHTML view. It seems that resolving the bean/method by EL expression does return a different bean instance.

Is the code given above the right way to get a reference to the bean/method? Has anyone an idea what's wrong here?

Thanks and regards

Comment: `ViewAccessScoped` or `ViewScoped`?

Comment: ViewAccessScoped in the end but I thought it may be not that different as ViewAccessScoped is just a little bit more long lived in certain circumstances.